# При каждом запуске терминала на mac появляется ошибка "permission denied"

Tags: python, консоль, nuitka

При каждом запуске терминала на mac появляется ошибка "permission denied". Полный текст:

*/Users/cedoeyxo/.zshrc:2: permission denied: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/nuitka*

Пытался получить доступ при помощи:

*sudo chown -R cedoeyxo $PATH*

получил, не помогло. Пытался удалить через pip (скорее всего через него ставил, наверное), такого модуля нет. Удалял ручками, при запуске терминала выдает *"no such file or directory"*.

Не понимаю, что он от меня хочет. Мне этот компилятор не нужен, я просто тестил его. Как полностью удалить его?